# SSAS 2008 - Best Practice to base Time dimension on own table?

Tags: time, ssas, olap, dimension

I am in the process of creating a star schema-based cube using SSAS 2008.

I would like advice on whether it is best practice to create my own date/time table in the DW database as the basis for the Time dimension or to use the 'generate a time table' in data source/on the server option in SSAS?

Second question: assuming 'generate in the data source' is not an option, which is better, create own table or generate on the server?

Two factors may influence the decision:

1) will be using YTD measures
2) will use Gregorian calendar in the first pass, but will be adding the Muslim calendar in second pass.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Well, if i say that it´s much easier and SSAS will do it very well, i.e. use the option "generate a time table" then your second question will be answered as well, i.e. generate on the server. I have done it and it works very good.